# Using VBA automatically update identically named sections in multiple docs

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I'm using VBA and MS Office (Excel, Word, and Project) to building system for managing multiple projects.
On thing I'd like to do is; with-in a project folder have matching sections of document's propagate changes, to the same titled section in another document.
For example, in a project I will have a ProjectCharter.docx, a CostEstimate.docx, and JobSpec.docx.  Although each doc is different, they will each have a "Project Title", and "Project Summary" section.
I'd like for the sections to all be the same, and for changes in a section in one doc to propagate to the same section in the rest of the docs.
It would be great  if I can make changes in any of the docs and onsaving have it propagate to the rest, but I'd still be totally satisfied if I had to use one as the master doc, and have it propagate changes from there.
Thanks

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/automatically-update-text-in-many-documents-3540388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any VBA code for this - all you need do is use Word's INCLUDETEXT fields. See:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-includetext-field-1c34d6d6-0de3-4b5c-916a-2ff950fb629e